# Relative path for OBR repository?

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-felix

Is it possible to specify a relative path to my [OBR](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html) repository when using Apache Felix with Maven?

For example, when I am configuring my maven-bundle-plugin, in the configuration section I have:

```
<configuration>
<instructions>
    <Bundle-Category>sample</Bundle-Category>
    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${artifactId}
                </Bundle-SymbolicName>
    <Export-Package>
        ${osgi.export} 
    </Export-Package>
</instructions>

<!-- OBR -->
<remoteOBR>repo-rel</remoteOBR>
<prefixUrl>file:///C:/Users/blah/obr-repo/releases</prefixUrl>
<ignoreLock>true</ignoreLock>
</configuration>
```

and  the same thing for distribution management:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <!-- Releases Repo -->
    <repository>
        <id>repo-rel</id>
        <url>file:///C:/Users/blah/obr-repo/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

If my Felix java project (container) is located at C:/Users/blah, can I just specify my OBR with relative path "obr-repo/releases"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BND plugin doesn't currently support relative URLs nor does the OBR URL handlers. It's just a bit of copy/paste functionality, so there's not really any transforming going on with the URLs.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "so there's not really any transforming going on with the URLs".

Comment: The URLs are not checked against any parent or current location. There are no semantic checks for "is this relative". All URLs are treated as absolute.